# CoreAnimation - Opacity Fade In and Out Animation Not Working

Tags: ios, core-animation, avfoundation, calayer, cakeyframeanimation

I'm attempting to create a fairly simple CoreAnimation for use in an `AVComposition`. My goal is to create a `CALayer` which, through various sublayers, fades a title in and out, then fades in an out images. A slideshow, basically. This is being exported to a .mov using `AVAssetWriter`.

With help from the WWDC 2011 AVEditDemo, I've been able to get a title and images appearing. The problem is that they are all on screen at the same time!

I have created each layer with an opacity of 0.0. I have then added an `CABasicAnimation` to fade them from 0.0 to 1.0, using the following code:

```
CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeInAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeInAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeInAnimation.additive = NO;
fadeInAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
fadeInAnimation.beginTime = 1.0;
fadeInAnimation.duration = 1.0;
fadeInAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[titleLayer addAnimation:fadeInAnimation forKey:nil];
```

The problem seems to be the 'beginTime' property. The "1.0" is meant to be a delay, so it starts 1 second after the start of the animation. However, it is appearing on the screen straight away. A fade out animation

The reverse of this code, for the fade out, simply changes the fromValue to 1.0 and the toValue to 0.0. It has a begin time of 4.0 and works perfectly.

I'm using the following to create the `animatedTitleLayer`:

```
CATextLayer *titleLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
titleLayer.string =self.album.title;
titleLayer.font = @"Helvetica";
titleLayer.fontSize = videoSize.height / 6;
titleLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
titleLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height / 6);
titleLayer.foregroundColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
titleLayer.opacity = 0.0;
```

The image fade in animations have a beginTime 5 seconds apart. Like the title, their fade out animations work fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

**EDIT**

The answers were all helpful, but ultimately I discovered that only one animation could be added to a `CALayer`. The fade out animation was working as it was the last one added.

I then tried a CAAnimationGroup, but this didn't work as I was modifying the same key value path.

So I've realised that a `CAKeyframeAnimation` is the best for this. Only I'm having some difficulty with that too! The code is now fading in okay, but it isn't fading out. I've tried various fillMode's, changed the duration, etc. Can't make it work!!

Here is my code:

```
    CAKeyframeAnimation *fadeInAndOut = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeInAndOut.duration = 5.0;
    fadeInAndOut.autoreverses = NO;
    fadeInAndOut.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                                                            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.0], 
                                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0], nil];

    fadeInAndOut.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], 
                                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], nil];
    fadeInAndOut.beginTime = 1.0;
    fadeInAndOut.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    fadeInAndOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
    [titleLayer addAnimation:fadeInAndOut forKey:nil];
```

Comment: so are you trying to have all the layers positioned and configured ahead of time, or can you add them as the slides transition through?

Comment: I'm positioning and configuring ahead of time. I figured it out thanks to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184803/what-kind-of-value-is-keytime-in-an-cakeyframeanimation

Comment: You have been able to export a CALayer to video? I'm stuck on that now. If you have any tips, please reply at my question. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285175/avfoundation-exporting-calayers-only

Comment: Keytimes should be a value between 0.0-1.0, according to Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cakeyframeanimation/1412522-keytimes

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm faced the same issue and the problem is - one layer can't contain fade in and out. 
So you can add the other animation to the parent layer as i did

```
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *animtingLayer = [CALayer layer];

//FADE IN
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation.beginTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(img.startTime);
        animation.duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(_timeline.transitionDuration);
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
        animation.additive = NO;
        [parentLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacityIN"];

//FADE OUT
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation.beginTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(CMTimeAdd(img.passTimeRange.start, img.passTimeRange.duration));
        animation.duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(_timeline.transitionDuration);
        animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
        animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
        animation.additive = NO;
        [animtingLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacityOUT"];

    [parentLayer addSublayer:animtingLayer];
```

Comment: I never would have figured this out. Thanks @comonitos

Comment: Maybe it's due to iOS 7 SDK's 2013-14 update or something I did differently, but adding **multiple** animations to one **layer** is possible currently, making it unnecessary to use extra layer @comonitos

Answer (score 26):

Man, so many complicated answers. The simplest way is just to add autoreverse. Voila.

```
CABasicAnimation *fadeInAndOut = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeInAndOut.duration = 5.0;
fadeInAndOut.autoreverses = YES;
fadeInAndOut.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
fadeInAndOut.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
fadeInAndOut.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
fadeInAndOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
[titleLayer addAnimation:fadeInAndOut forKey:@"myanimation"];
```

Comment: This solution starts the fade out as soon as the fade has completed. I'm guessing OP wants the title to fade in, stay visible for a bit, then fade out.

Comment: Indeed best answer. I would add for those who are struggling, you also may want to add  [yourView setWantsLayer:YES]; before getting your view's layer. By default views don't have layers.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
 let fadeAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath:"opacity")
 fadeAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero + start
 fadeAnimation.duration = duration
 fadeAnimation.keyTimes = [0, 1/8.0, 5/8.0, 1]
 fadeAnimation.values = [0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
 fadeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
 fadeAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
 layer.addAnimation(fadeAnimation, forKey:"animateOpacity")
 layer.opacity = 0.0
```

Comment: Nice answer :) in func

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
fadeInAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()+1.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from the link mentioned by gamblor87 and adding my comments as explanation.

```
//create a fadeInOut CAKeyframeAnimation on opacticy
CAKeyframeAnimation *fadeInAndOut = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];

//set duration
fadeInAndOut.duration = 5.0;

//autoreverses defaults to NO so we don't need this.
//fadeInAndOut.autoreverses = NO;

//keyTimes are time points on duration timeline as a fraction of animation duration (here 5 seconds).
fadeInAndOut.keyTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.20],
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.80], 
                                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];


//set opacity values at various points during the 5second animation
fadeInAndOut.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],//opacity 0 at 0s (corresponds to keyTime = 0s/5s)
                                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],//opacity 1 at 1s (corresponds to keyTime = 1s/5s)
                                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],//opacity 1 upto 4s (corresponds to keyTime = 4s/5s)
                                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],//opacity 0 at 5s (corresponds to keyTime = 5s/5s)
 nil];

//delay in start of animation. What we are essentially saying is to start the 5second animation after 1second.
fadeInAndOut.beginTime = 1.0;

//don't remove the animation on completion.
fadeInAndOut.removedOnCompletion = NO;

//fill mode. In most cases we won't need this.
fadeInAndOut.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;

//add the animation to layer
[titleLayer addAnimation:fadeInAndOut forKey:nil];
```

Comment: fadeInAndOut.beginTime = 1.0 doesn't work, you need to use CACurrentMediaTime() + 1;

Answer (score 2):

The point is key name. You have to set the opacity key.

```
layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)         // Not Working
layer.add(animation, forKey: "opacity")   // Working
```

Check the sample code. I tested in Swift 4

```
    let animation                   = CAKeyframeAnimation()
    animation.duration              = 1.53
    animation.autoreverses          = false
    animation.keyTimes              = [0, 0.51, 0.85, 1.0]
    animation.values                = [0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5]
    animation.beginTime             = 0
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    animation.fillMode              = kCAFillModeBoth
    animation.repeatCount           = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
    layer.add(animation, forKey: "opacity")
```

Comment: Adding: you can set the key either in `layer.add` or in `CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")`

Answer (score 1):

The core of the problem was not understanding the keyTimes property of a CAKeyframeAnimation. This question clarified it all and set me down the right path:

[What kind of value is keyTime in an CAKeyFrameAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184803/what-kind-of-value-is-keytime-in-an-cakeyframeanimation)

Answer (score 1):

[LenK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376099/lenk)'s answer worked perfectly for me. If anyone is interested, I re-wrote for Obj-C (note I also slightly changed the key frames on fade in):

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *fadeInAndOutAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
fadeInAndOutAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + beginTime;
fadeInAndOutAnimation.duration = duration;
fadeInAndOutAnimation.keyTimes = @[@0.0, @( 2.0 / 8.0 ), @( 5.0 / 8.0 ), @1.0];
fadeInAndOutAnimation.values = @[@0.0, @1.0, @1.0, @0.0];
fadeInAndOutAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false;
fadeInAndOutAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```

Comment: This worked well for me but you need to add one additional line: `fadeInAndOutAnimation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;`. Otherwise the view fades out once and never appears again.

Answer (score 1):

Look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44204846/667483

In summary: to use `beginTime` you should set fillMode to `kCAFillModeBackwards` on you animation object.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative way is the using CAAnimationGroup. CAKeyframeAnimation also works fine for UI. This code works fine in UI for show animation real-time. But **will not work at all** in `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` - please scroll down if you need it. It is not code ready for copy-paste but you can get the idea. Also, you can add addition animations to the group:

```
for (HKAnimatedLayer *animLayer in layersList) {

    overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    [overlayLayer setContents:(id)[animLayer.image CGImage]];
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    [overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    NSMutableArray *animations = [NSMutableArray array];
    // Step 1
    {
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation.toValue = @(0);
        animation.duration = kLayerFadeDuration;
        animation.beginTime = kMovieDuration/5;
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        [animations addObject:animation];
    }
    {
        CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation.toValue = @(1.0);
        animation.duration = kLayerFadeDuration;
        animation.beginTime = kMovieDuration*2/3;
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        [animations addObject:animation];
    }

    CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animationGroup.animations = animations;
    animationGroup.duration = kMovieDuration;
    animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    [overlayLayer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:nil];

    [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];
}
```

Here small note about animation on layers for `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`. You can see relevant gif image (titles should appear and disappear one by one). To solve this issue I use 2 separate `CALayer`'s because for some reason on one layer 2 `opaque` animations on multiple layers are glitched.

[image: AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool]

```
// set up the parent layer
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

// one layer for one animation
CALayer *overlayLayer, *barrierLayer;
CABasicAnimation *animation;

for (HKAnimatedLayer *animLayer in layersList) {
    overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
    overlayLayer.contents = (id)[animLayer.image CGImage];
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    overlayLayer.masksToBounds = YES;

    // layer with appear animation
    if (animLayer.fromTime != 0 && (animLayer.fromTime - kLayerFadeDuration)>0) {
        overlayLayer.opacity = 0.0;

        animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation.fromValue = @(0);
        animation.toValue = @(1);
        animation.additive = NO;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        animation.beginTime = animLayer.fromTime - kLayerFadeDuration;
        animation.duration = kLayerFadeDuration;
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

        [overlayLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"fadeIn"];
    }

    if (animLayer.toTime == kMovieDuration) {
        [parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];
    } else { // layer with dissappear animation
        barrierLayer = [CALayer layer];
        barrierLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        barrierLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
        [barrierLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];

        animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation.fromValue = @(1);
        animation.toValue = @(0);
        animation.additive = NO;
        animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        animation.beginTime = animLayer.toTime;
        animation.duration = kLayerFadeDuration;
        animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

        [overlayLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"fadeOut"];
        [parentLayer addSublayer:barrierLayer];
    }
}
```

And at the end, we can get proper animation sequence [image: right animation]