# How to add fade in out animation between each image frame in video

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am making video from images in my new app. I need to add some fadeIn - Out animation between each frame. Is it possible to add some animation between each image frame in video.

Please let me know if you have any solution or peice of code for it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes,it is possible.But what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have not tried any method , need to get that

Comment: Hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707104/coreanimation-opacity-fade-in-and-out-animation-not-working