# how to add fade in and fade out effect on image in video and generate new video in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, video

I am working on application in which I have to merge fade in and fade out effect with existing video.
I know how to merge videos using `AVMutableComposition`, We can make a video from the images using `AVAssetWriter`,
but my problem is, how to merge image fade in effect at starting of video and image fade out effect at ending of video.

Comment: I got the solution of my problem from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11327234/3384769) link

Answer (score 0):

```
    //for fed in
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

            _image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
// for fed out
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{

                _image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
            }completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
        }];
```

I hope that help you.

Comment: I got this solution in during research work but I have to merge this effect with existing video to generate new video.